# get variable name in debugger visualizer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, debuggervisualizer

Is there a way to get the underlying variable name of a target object in a Visual Studio debugger visualizer?  The built-in string visualizer does it:

```
string myStr = "abc\ndef";
Debugger.Break();
```

Clicking on the visualizer icon for `myStr`, you will see the "Expression" text box shows "myStr".  How can I get this in my own visualizers?

Comment: +1, I hope someone can help, but I fear that without access to the internal DebugeeHost class it's not going to happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visualized expression in custom data visualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749716/visualized-expression-in-custom-data-visualizer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible to do.  The only information provided to the visualizer is the value.

The string visualizer has the name because it is in fact not a true visualizer.  That is, it's a debugger feature which has a greater level of access to the underlying metadata and more importantly the expression evaluators.