# Visualized expression in custom data visualizer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visualizer

When I choose one of the built-in visualizers:

[image: Choosing a visualizer]

I can see the original expression being visualized:

[image: Text visualizer, with circled visualized expression]

**How can I get this information from within my own custom visualizer?**

I've looked through the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/visualizer-api-reference?view=vs-2017), without finding anything.

(If you haven't found an answer, please upvote the [request to support this on Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/503782/api-for-visualized-expression-in-custom-visualizer.html).)

**Update**

The linked Developer Community request has been closed for *reasons*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago, I asked the PM of the Visual Studio Debugger the same question in the comments in of one of his blog posts. I searched my email archive and found a mail from February 04, 2006:

My question was:

> ... I also would like to know how the Visualizers provided by VS2005
> manage to display the expression (topmost textbox in the Visualizer
> form).

And the answer:

> ... The reason the string visualizers can display the original
> expression is that they are built into Visual Studio at a lower level
> than the Visualizers interface we provide. They are written in native
> code and work when debugging native code, while the visualizers
> architecture we provide is limited to managed code.
>
> Sorry!
>
> Let me know if you have any more questions.
>
> Scott Nonnenberg
>
> Program Manager Visual C# Team

This was on http://blogs.msdn.com/scottno/default.aspx but I think Scott is no longer a Microsoft employee and the posting won't be available online...

It is quite probable that this has not changed - even in VS2019 where the mechanism was modified to work with .Net Core.